# Where to put resources (css/images) in CodeIgniter?

Tags: codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I am doing some testing with CI and have it running in a folder. http://www.example.com/sub-folder/ for instance

My directory structure is like this (where / is sub-folder/):
/
|-/system
|-/application

I have eclipse as my IDE with 2 projects, 1 for system, 1 for application, where application is my project that includes a reference to system.

My .htaccess file prevents access to system directory. I would like to have my images and CSS placed into: application/resources/images and application/resources/css respectively. I would like to be able to use `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/sub-folder/css/style.css" />` However, after spending some time testing and searching, I haven't been able to get the CSS file to load from the application directory.

What do I need to change or add in my .htaccess to be able to do this?

The contents of my .htaccess follows:

`<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteBase /`

```
### Canonicalize codeigniter URLs

# If your default controller is something other than
# "welcome" you should probably change this
RewriteRule ^(welcome(/index)?|index(\.php)?)/?$ / [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/index/?$ $1 [L,R=301]

# Removes trailing slashes (prevents SEO duplicate content issues)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ $1 [L,R=301]

# Removes access to the system folder by users.
# Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
# previously this would not have been possible.
# 'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

# Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
# such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
# request to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/sub-folder/css/style.css" />
```

You could do

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url('application/sub-folder/css/style.css'); ?>" />
```

I usually keep my assets in the root folder (where the main index.php file is) and use [this asset library](http://getsparks.org/packages/assets/versions/HEAD/show) to load everything.

If you want to keep your assets in `application/sub-folder` you could do this:

Comment: Thanks for your answer however If I put the assets into the root folder then they would be outside of my eclipse project which is what I wanted to avoid. I am using `base_url('sub-folder/css/style.css')` but thought I'd show `/sub-folder/css/style.css` for simplicity sake.

Comment: `base_url('sub-folder/css/style.css')` will look in the root of your application for the *sub-folder*. You would need to use `base_url('application/sub-folder/css/style.css')`. I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: I tried this and the HTML output is: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.example.com/sub-folder/application/css/style.css" />` is there something wrong with my configuration?

Comment: It flips *application* and *sub-folder* around? That's weird. What do you have your base_url set to? Did you try `site_url()` in place of `base_url()`?

Comment: Sorry my mistake, the output is: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.example.com/sub-folder/application/resources/css/style.css" />` when `base_url('application/resources/css/main.css')` is used. The .htaccess and index.php files are inside `sub-folder`. I have also tried `site_url()` with the same results. Also, `$config['base_url'] = 'http://www.example.com/sub-folder/';`.

Comment: Oh, I actually bet it's an issue with the RewriteBase you have set. Setting it to "/" will look in the server's root. You probably need to set it "/sub-folder".

Comment: I adjusted the .htaccess like this: `RewriteBase /sub-folder`
`RewriteRule ^css/([A-Za-z0-9-].+)$   application/resources/css/$1 [L]` however it only worked when I removed the .htaccess file from the application folder. Do I have to set my routes differently to allow this? I used the rewrite rule tester at http://martinmelin.se/rewrite-rule-tester/ to make sure that my rewrite rule was correct.

Comment: I am now using `base_url('css/main.css')`

Answer (score 0):

I set up my CI projects like this:

- application (my application files)
- assets (publicly accessible css, js and images etc)
- system (codeigniter core)

Typically, if I'm building in a CMS I'll put the CMS assets inside the application folder since they're basically private.